# How to build a flask template with a list of json elements?

Tags: json, templates, flask

I'm pretty sure this should be an easy one. I am using Flask, and i am buildeing a template that gets a list of jeson elements. I wish to buil a table that lists those elements in an ordered manner, with reading specific attributes of each of the json elements in the list. the code i have been using is as follows:

```
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
   <h1> Users are: </h1>
   <table>
    <tr>
        <th>user name</th>
        <th>user fb_id</th>
        <th>user mt_id</th>
        <th>user ts_last_show_request</th>
    </tr>
    {% for item in users %}
    <tr>
        <td>item[fb_name]</td>
        <td>item[fb_uid]</td>
        <td>item[mt_uid]</td>
        <td>item[ts_last_show_request]</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
   </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

But this code simply creates a nice table heading with a list of identical rows that don't interpret the 'item[mt_uid]' commands, but simply lists them.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do this:

```
<tr>
  <td>{{ item[fb_name] }}</td>
  <td>{{ item[fb_uid]  }}</td>
  <!-- etc. -->
</tr>
```